# Три письма, подписанныХ Вами или три письма, подписанныЕ Вами - как правильно?

Tags: числительные

Три письма, подписанныХ Вами или три письма, подписанныЕ Вами - как правильно написать?

Answer (score 2):

Причастие должно стоять в том же падеже, что и существительное. Правильно: подписанных. Каких письма - подписанных. Какие письма - подписанные - напр.: письма, подписанные начальником.

Comment: Полная фраза: В период июль-август мною получено три письма, подписанныХ(Е). Падеж винительный? Или родительный?

Comment: Три письма - род.пад. Правильно: подписанных.

Answer (score 1):

Три подписанных документа. Сравните: "Три ненастных дня".
Три подписанных письма.
Три подписанные записки. Три красивые девушки.

Если же это распространенное определение после определяемого слова, то думаю, что оба варианта допустимы.

Comment: Три подписанных документа (каких документов - подписанных). Три ненастных дня (каких - ненастных - род.пад. - Определение, стоящее между числительными два, три, четыре и последующим существительным, обычно употребляется в форме родительного падежа множественного числа при словах мужского и среднего рода (два больших дома, два больших окна) и в форме именительного падежа множественного числа при словах женского рода). Три красивые девушки (ед. ч. имен. пад.). А причастие должно стоять в том же падеже, что и сущ.

Comment: Числительные два, три, четыре (а также составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два) в именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного падежа и единственного числа, например: двадцать два стола, тридцать три несчастья. Отсюда: три письма (род. пад. Причаст.подписанных - род.под). Но: Письма(имен. пад.) подписанные начальником...

Comment: Это не ответ.
Почему все же три (каких - сильных) парня - это родительный падеж, а три (какие - красивые) девушки - это вдруг именительный?
Не надо ничего выдумывать, просто зависит от рода. А вот почему зависит - это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Niemand, в женском роде определение употребляется в именительном падеже. Правила создавал не я. Читать надо внимательно!

Comment: На вопрос: какое окончание в  должно быть в этих предложеиях: (Вопрос № 277365) "написаны людьми, не скрывающИХ своих фамилий...". ; <...> сейчас захвачен вооруженными ЛЮДЬМИ в форме без опознавательных знаков, но НЕ СКРЫВАЮЩИХ своей принадлежности к России.".



   
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Причастие должно стоять в том же падеже, что и существительное: людьми (какими?) -  не скрывающими; людей (каких?) -  не скрывающих. В обеих приведенных фразах одна и та же грамматическая ошибка. В обоих случаях следовало написать: не скрывающими.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: "Три письма, подписанных Вами", так как письмо - сущ. ср.р.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Существует правило:

Форма ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ  в количественно-именных словосочетаниях с числительными два, три, четыре зависит ОТ РОДА имени существительного:

А) три высокие пальмы, две большие ложки – И. п. прилагательных для сущ. ж. р.:

Б)  два высоких дерева, три больших ведра – Р. п. прилагательных для сущ. м.р. и ср.р.

2)  А как объяснить это правило?

Основной формой  для прилагательного является Р.п.: два больших дерева (согласование в Р.п.).

Форма  И.п. (три высокие пальмы, две маленькие девочки) является ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНОЙ и удобна  в том случае, когда для существительного ЖЕНСКОГО РОДА с точностью до ударения СОВПАДАЮТ формы И.п. мн.числа  и Р.п. ед. числа: девочки (мн.ч.) – нет девочки (ед.ч.). В этом случае  сочетание    «маленьких девочки» воспринимается на слух как нежелательное, лучше звучит  «маленькие девочки». Это известный в языке принцип сочетаемости рядом расположенных слов.

А теперь возьмем существительное ж.р. , для которого эти формы не совпадают по ударению: стенЫ – стЕны. Две окрашенных  стены или две окрашенные стены?  Здесь "правильного" сочетания нет в обоих случаях, поэтому удобнее пользоваться общим правилом.

А если определение обособленное? В этом случае  тем более нет необходимости использовать И.п., оба варианта на слух воспринимаются одинаково. Но в любом случае лучше ориентироваться на формальное правило, например: два города, расположенных поблизости; две стены, окрашенные в светлые тона.

Comment: Вопрос № 277259   
  

    Пожалуйста, разъясните с указанием на правила, как будет правильно написать: "Сепаратисты утверждают, что на востоке Украины окружили две крупные группировки (или 2 крупных группировки) украинских военных". Спасибо. 

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

    При существительных женского рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре, определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, чаще ставится в форме именительного падежа множественного числа: две крупные группировки. Но и вариант две крупных группировки возможен, это не ошибка.

Comment: В ответе не хватает анализа: зачем нам две формы, если они обе допускаются, и чем они вообще отличаются.

Comment: София, написано же:возможен, не будет ошибкой. Но в любом случае удобный вариант им.пад.

Comment: Правило должно быть понятным. Иногда нам удобно соблюсти сочетаемость, а иногда - без разницы. А то получается, что кто-то придумал неясное правило, которому следовать не всегда обязательно. Это расстраивает общественность и дискредитирует орфографию  как точную науку.

Comment: Вот , прочитайте:  [Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Comment: Замечательное правило, не хватает только заключительного тезиса  о сочетаемости. А в действительности с этого тезиса надо начинать тему: чтобы обеспечить сочетаемость, вместо обычного Р.п. используется частный  И.п. и т.д. Правильное рассуждение должно строиться от общего к частному. Мне иногда кажется, что наши правила похожи на ребусы: начало в них перемешано с концом,  а что-то главное  непременно не досказывается.

Comment: Действительно, в наших правилах большой разнобой.